# Manually override Quartus Fitter/Pin Assignment constraints

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I have a design that I want to synthesize for / upload to a Max 10 FPGA.

One of the inputs goes to a PLL. Quartus now claims, that the neighbouring IO pin is too close to the PLL input pin and won't let me use it.

Is there any way that I can force Quartus to ignore this restriction, provided I am willing to take the risk of the design not working as expected?

(I have changed my board design for the next iteration so that this won't be a problem in the future.)

Comment: You have to add more details. What kind of  IO pin it is you trying to map, how frequently it toggles etc.

Comment: If the EDA is not letting you make the assignment, it's because you shouldn't be making the assignment, whether you are willing to take a risk or not. Generally in these situations, the vendor knows best.